# How to retrieve the background images of Windows 10 lock screen?

Tags: windows-10

These images seem to change constantly, every time it's a completely new image. Where do they come from, is there a way to retrieve them somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about the windows spotlight pictures, the files themselves are in the following folder:

`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`

Copy these files to a different folder. Now start changing the filenames to `YourNameHere.jpg`in order from biggest file size to lowest. (You can sort by file size to help.)

Another trick is to use the command prompt to rename them all in one fell swoop instead of manually renaming them. Open the command prompt, navigate to the directory you put the files in, and then use `ren * *.jpg*` to get them all.

**Caution:** Make sure you only have the files you wish to rename in the directory you run this in, since it will rename *everything*.

Comment: in the folder you mentioned I did find the spotlight picture currently used in lock screen, however all the ones I saw before aren't there. It is as if Windows deletes the current image before replacing it with the next one. Any input on this?

Comment: I believe it naturally cycles them out. If it's not there, I would google the most recent spotlight images and see if you can get it online. That's the best I got for you though, sorry!

Comment: Actually I just checked again this folder because the new spotlight picture on my computer is nice. It's not there :( So sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Thanks Microsoft for that completely unnecessary and utterly annoying decision to make such pictures hard to retrieve.

Answer (score -2):

To tweak your lock screen to your liking, select the Start button, then select Settings > Personalization > Lock screen. Try changing the background to a favourite photo or slideshow, or choose any combination of detailed and quick status notifications to show you upcoming calendar events, social network updates, and other app and system notifications.

[image: screenshot]

---

### Edit

Misunderstood of the OP question sorry about that.

---

[From Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17185/windows-10-lock-screen)

Comment: The OP is not asking how to change the setting, he is asking where the image files are kept (the Windows spotlight backgrounds).

Comment: Thanks, @El8tedN8te I've edited my post I don't know if I should completely delete it?